# Yii URLManager and action parameter

Tags: php, yii

When i turned off URL manager in config

```
index.php?r=cars/car_detail&id=2&type=delete
```

Displays expected result which is delete
My controller code is:

```
public function actionCar_detail($id = 0, $type = '')
{
     die($type);
     //codes
}
```

When i turned on URL manager,
Type is empty, why is it behave differently? Please help me been stuck with this for some time now. THanks

Comment: URL must be index.php/cars/car_detail/id/2/type/delete is it ?

Comment: `controller/method/param1/value1/param2/value2` when you turn on URL manager.

Comment: or paste your URL manager config setting

Comment: @itachi, thanks alot, it was what i was looking for. please write it as answer. GBD, is it possible for it to happen as such my url?

Comment: i wasn't aware of this because as you can see when its car_detail/2, it working fine tho? without /id/ ?

Comment: @joh sorry i didn't get you `GBD, is it possible for it to happen as such my url?`

Comment: sorry i looked wrongly at your comment, i think you could answer it too as you answered it first correctly. The url i was looking for  index.php/cars/car_detail/2/delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above case, the url will become

```
index.php/cars/car_detail/id/2/type/delete
```

the above will output on `print_r($_GET);`

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [type] => delete
)
```

Use the variable as you want.

in general, the syntax is:

```
controller/method/param1/value1/param2/value2/......
```

Answer (score 0):

to work inside the url manager the url structure defaulted to /controller/actionname?params

so

```
 /index.php?r=cars/car_detail&id=2&type=delete
```

in the url manager it means just query string r
to format it as default url

```
/car/car_details?id=2&type=delete
```

this url will go to car controller then action car_details and the parameters id and type are set